# Quick question about the term ‘integrable’

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If a math textbook or paper just uses the term “integrable”, for example: 
$$f(x)  \ \text{is integrable on} \ [a,b],$$
do we always assume this means Riemann integrable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing certain about $f$ being integrable. It can be Riemann integrable, Lebesgue, Stjeltjes, and so on

Comment: No, in general you cannot assume this. However, in most introductory books on real analysis it is usually taken to mean Riemann/Darboux integrability (they are equivalent).

Comment: write a function as $f(x)$ instead of just $f$ make me think that this is an elementary book, so probably it will mean that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the context. For instance, the function
$f: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{ if }x \in \mathbb Q \\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
is Lebesgue integrable but not Riemann integrable.